# Sitecore Content Hub filtering for relations field

Tags: content-hub, dam

Does anyone of you encountered this problem after upgrade to 4.2.25?
In my asset details component, I have a relations field: Campaign
filtered by Brand & Market so that the available values for Campaign will be based on the selection made for Brand & Market fields.
When I tried to set the Campaign in an asset, all Campaigns are shown instead of the filtered ones based on the Brand & Market I selected prior.[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a Taxonomy configuration adjustment to me. Here is a similar use case and link that will help you to understand the configuration in great detail.

The use case is the following: We have a Taxonomy “Category” and a Taxonomy “Section”, both are related to M.Asset and Subcategory is dependent on the Category.

**Credit:** https://anbrue.net/2021/09/06/content-hub-dependent-fields-on-entity-details-component/

Hope it helps!